# Unable to enroll Fabric client as admin - Amazon Managed Blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, amazon-managed-blockchain

I'm following the AWS supply chain workshop. I created an EC2 instance and set up a VPC just like the workshop said. Now I'm connected to the EC2 instance using SSH and I've already downloaded the required packages, setup Docker, downloaded fabric-ca-client. My problem is configuring the fabric-ca client.

When I run the command `fabric-ca-client enroll` with the required params/flags, it retuns the following error: `Error: Failed to create default configuration file: Failed to parse URL 'https://$USER:=9_phK63?@$CA_ENDPOINT': parse https://user:password@ca_endpoint: invalid port ":=9_phK63?" after host`

Here's the complete command I'm trying to run: `fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://$USER\:$PASSWORD@$CA_ENDPOINT --tls.certfiles ~/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem -M admin-msp -H $HOME`

I'm wondering if the `?` in the password is causing the problem. If so, where can I change it?

Workshop link for reference: https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/ce1e960e-a811-475f-a221-2afcf57e386a/en-US/02-set-up-a-fabric-client/05-configure-client/06-create-fabric-admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my name is Forrest and I am a Blockchain Specialist Solutions Architect at AWS. I'd be happy to help you with this.

When using passwords with special characters, these need to be URL-encoded. For example, `$` equates to `%24`. As OP mentioned in comments below, there is a Javascript method `encodeURIComponent()` that can serve this function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Please make sure your environment variables are all still correctly set as well:

```
echo $USER
echo $PASSWORD
echo $CA_ENDPOINT
```

Your CA endpoint should resolve to something like:
`ca.m-XXXXXXXXXXXXX.n-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.managedblockchain.<AWS_REGION>.amazonaws.com:30002`

Comment: I've just found out that I needed to URL-encode the password (I think this is the correct term). To do it I used the `encodeURIComponent` from the Javascript API. The password in the post is not the same I'm using for development. Also, I tried to espace every special character on the password with a backslash and it didn't work.

Comment: If you create a new answer with another proven solution or the one I commented on earlier, I'd be happy to mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Yes, URL encoding would have been the next step of troubleshooting. Glad you figured this out. I will amend my answer for others who may come across this.

Comment: I've updated my answer with reference to URL encoding, as this is the best solution rather than manually handling the password. Thanks!